More efficient way to replace `.loc` method with chaining in Pandas DataFrame operations
I'm currently working on a project where I need to perform conditional replacements in a Pandas DataFrame. I've implemented a solution, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve the same result.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emma'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix']
}
df_init = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Using `.loc`
df_init['Group'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df_init.loc[df_init.loc[
            (df_init.City=='New York')
            &(df_init.Name=='Alice')].index, 'City'] = 'Hamburg' 

# Using method chaining
def _replace(dataframe): 
    dataframe.loc[dataframe.loc[
                 (dataframe.City=='New York')
                 &(dataframe.Name=='Alice')].index, 'City'] = 'Hamburg' 
    return dataframe

(df_init
 .assign(Group=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
 .pipe(_replace)
)

In the first method, I'm using the .loc method to locate the row where the conditions are met and then perform the replacement. In the second approach, I'm using method chaining with .assign and .pipe to achieve the same result.
My question is: Is there a more efficient way to replace the .loc method with method chaining in Pandas DataFrame operations? I should mention that I am very new to the methods chaining world of pandas.

Are you aware of the pandas.DataFrame.where() function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)? I feel like it might solve your problem but I'm not sure.

Code
make condition and use mask func.
cond = df_init['City'].eq('New York') & df_init['Name'].eq('Alice')
out = df_init.assign(
    Group = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
    City=df_init['City'].mask(cond, 'Hamburg')
)

out
      Name  Age         City Group
0    Alice   25      Hamburg     A
1      Bob   30  Los Angeles     B
2  Charlie   35      Chicago     C
3    David   40      Houston     D
4     Emma   45      Phoenix     E


Don't mutate a DataFrame in a pipe call. I would use mask with a lambda/callable:
out = df_init.assign(Group=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                     City=lambda d: d['City'].mask(d['City'].eq('New York')&d['Name'].eq('Alice'), 'Hamburg')

Output:
      Name  Age         City
0    Alice   25      Hamburg
1      Bob   30  Los Angeles
2  Charlie   35      Chicago
3    David   40      Houston
4     Emma   45      Phoenix


There are a few different options that you can use that include using method chaining with pipe or you can use np.where. given your question, I tested out both of the below with the time:
Using pipe:
def _replace(dataframe):
    dataframe.loc[(dataframe.City=='New York') & (dataframe.Name=='Alice'), 'City'] = 'Hamburg'
    return dataframe

def method_pipe(df):
    return (df
            .assign(Group=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
            .pipe(_replace)
           )

np.where:
def method_where(df):
    return df.assign(
        Group=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        City=np.where((df['City'] == 'New York') & (df['Name'] == 'Alice'), 'Hamburg', df['City'])
    )

I tested both of them and below is the time taken using programiz online python compiler:
{'loc': 0.0017023086547851562, 'pipe': 0.0009500980377197266, 'where': 0.0007925033569335938}

